# Problem with SweetAlert2 and Ionic6 not visualizing correctly

Tags: javascript, angular, ionic-framework, ionic6

I have a Ionic Project written on Ionic 5 Angular that has some popups using SweetAlerts2.

Today I decided to update Ionic to Ionic6 and SweetAlerts2 popups doesn't look right. Like the alert is only visible on the header and everything else is blank.

Screenshot of the problem:

[Ionic6 Visualization Problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lNr8z.png)

Code:

```
swal.fire({
  html:
    '<br><label style="font-size:80%">Example Alert</label>',
  showDenyButton: true,
  confirmButtonText: "Confirm",
  denyButtonText: "Deny",
  denyButtonColor: 'grey',
  confirmButtonColor: 'var(--ion-color-primary)',
})
```

[Repository where the problem is reproduced](https://github.com/murapa96/Ionic6SweetAlert)

Comment: Please give us a some [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: I will make a new github repository with an example, give me some minutes.

Comment: The reproducible example is added on a github repository

Comment: In ionic, you have to set the heightAuto to false eg  Swal.fire({title:'Title',heightAuto:false})

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This has been addressed in this [issue](https://github.com/sweetalert2/sweetalert2/issues/1111)

Simply use this option with Ionic Framework.

```
heightAuto: false
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I was looking on the issues of Ionic and not on SweetAlert2 ones.

Comment: It works, thanks, I'm using Angular version 14, "@sweetalert2/ngx-sweetalert2": "^11.0.0" and "sweetalert2": "^11.7.3",

Comment: my problem was with the background of the alert was not visible but this gave the alert background the right opacity. Thanks

Comment: Thanks it is working to me using Angular version 16 and Ionic 7